# Powershell: Replace special characters

Tags: special-characters, powershell-2.0

Is there an easy way to replace special characters, like æøåéü etc., from a string in a Powershell script?

Making the string web-safe.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "easy way". And what you want to replace them with? Just remove them, or have some replacement-table to use us reference?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the bad explanation. I looking for a function that can make a string web-safe. I.e. the Å will be replaced by 'aa' and é with e etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with additional explanation, I guess solution would depend on a scale. If that's user input and in "normal" use it would be short, that maybe something like that:

```
$Replacer = @{
    Å = 'aa'
    é = 'e'
}

$string_to_fix = 'æøåéüÅ'

$pattern = "[$(-join $Replacer.Keys)]"

[regex]::Replace($string_to_fix, $pattern, { $Replacer[$args[0].value] })
```

Obviously, you would have to fill in the blanks for $Replacer ;)
HTH
Bartek