# Won't replace string with special characters

Tags: powershell, replace, special-characters, powershell-2.0

```
function replaceSpecialCharacters($strRemove)
{
    $arrWrapper = @()
    $arrWrapper = $arrWrapper + 1
    $arrWrapper = $arrWrapper + 2

    $arrReplace = @()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 75; $i++)
    {
        $arrReplace += @($false)
    }

    $arrReplaceWith=@()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 75; $i++)
    {
        $arrReplaceWith += @($false)
    }
    $arrWrapper[0] = $arrReplace
    $arrWrapper[1] = $arrReplace

    $arrWrapper[0][0] = "?"
    $arrWrapper[0][1] = "?"
    $arrWrapper[0][2] = "Ð"
    $arrWrapper[0][3] = "d"
    $arrWrapper[0][4] = "?"
    $arrWrapper[0][5] = "?"
    $arrWrapper[0][6] = "C"
    $arrWrapper[0][7] = "c"
    $arrWrapper[0][8] = "C"
    $arrWrapper[0][9] = "c"
    $arrWrapper[0][10] = "À"
    $arrWrapper[0][11] = "Á"
    $arrWrapper[0][12] = "Â"
    $arrWrapper[0][13] = "Ã"
    $arrWrapper[0][14] = "Ä"
    $arrWrapper[0][15] = "Å"
    $arrWrapper[0][16] = "Æ"
    $arrWrapper[0][17] = "Ç"
    $arrWrapper[0][18] = "È"
    $arrWrapper[0][19] = "É"
    $arrWrapper[0][20] = "Ê"
    $arrWrapper[0][21] = "Ë"
    $arrWrapper[0][22] = "Ì"
    $arrWrapper[0][23] = "Í"
    $arrWrapper[0][24] = "Î"
    $arrWrapper[0][25] = "Ï"
    $arrWrapper[0][26] = "Ñ"
    $arrWrapper[0][27] = "Ò"
    $arrWrapper[0][28] = "Ó"
    $arrWrapper[0][29] = "Ô"
    $arrWrapper[0][30] = "Õ"
    $arrWrapper[0][31] = "Ö"
    $arrWrapper[0][32] = "Ø"
    $arrWrapper[0][33] = "Ù"
    $arrWrapper[0][34] = "Ú"
    $arrWrapper[0][35] = "Û"
    $arrWrapper[0][36] = "Ü"
    $arrWrapper[0][37] = "Ý"
    $arrWrapper[0][38] = "Þ"
    $arrWrapper[0][39] = "ß"
    $arrWrapper[0][40] = "à"
    $arrWrapper[0][41] = "á"
    $arrWrapper[0][42] = "â"
    $arrWrapper[0][43] = "ã"
    $arrWrapper[0][44] = "ä"
    $arrWrapper[0][45] = "å"
    $arrWrapper[0][46] = "æ"
    $arrWrapper[0][47] = "ª"
    $arrWrapper[0][48] = "ç"
    $arrWrapper[0][49] = "è"
    $arrWrapper[0][50] = "é"
    $arrWrapper[0][51] = "ê"
    $arrWrapper[0][52] = "ë"
    $arrWrapper[0][53] = "ì"
    $arrWrapper[0][54] = "í"
    $arrWrapper[0][55] = "î"
    $arrWrapper[0][56] = "ï"
    $arrWrapper[0][57] = "ð"
    $arrWrapper[0][58] = "ñ"
    $arrWrapper[0][59] = "ò"
    $arrWrapper[0][60] = "ó"
    $arrWrapper[0][61] = "ô"
    $arrWrapper[0][62] = "õ"
    $arrWrapper[0][63] = "ö"
    $arrWrapper[0][64] = "ø"
    $arrWrapper[0][65] = "ù"
    $arrWrapper[0][66] = "ú"
    $arrWrapper[0][67] = "û"
    $arrWrapper[0][68] = "ü"
    $arrWrapper[0][69] = "ý"
    $arrWrapper[0][70] = "ý"
    $arrWrapper[0][71] = "þ"
    $arrWrapper[0][72] = "ÿ"
    $arrWrapper[0][73] = "R"
    $arrWrapper[0][74] = "r"

    $arrWrapper[1][0] = "S"
    $arrWrapper[1][1] = "s"
    $arrWrapper[1][2] = "Dj"
    $arrWrapper[1][3] = "d"
    $arrWrapper[1][4] = "Z"
    $arrWrapper[1][5] = "z"
    $arrWrapper[1][6] = "C"
    $arrWrapper[1][7] = "c"
    $arrWrapper[1][8] = "C"
    $arrWrapper[1][9]= "c"
    $arrWrapper[1][10] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][11] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][12] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][13] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][14] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][15] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][16] = "A"
    $arrWrapper[1][17] = "C"
    $arrWrapper[1][18] = "E"
    $arrWrapper[1][19] = "E"
    $arrWrapper[1][20] = "E"
    $arrWrapper[1][21] = "E"
    $arrWrapper[1][22] = "I"
    $arrWrapper[1][23] = "I"
    $arrWrapper[1][24] = "I"
    $arrWrapper[1][25] = "I"
    $arrWrapper[1][26] = "N"
    $arrWrapper[1][27] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][28] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][29] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][30] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][31] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][32] = "O"
    $arrWrapper[1][33] = "U"
    $arrWrapper[1][34] = "U"
    $arrWrapper[1][35] = "U"
    $arrWrapper[1][36] = "U"
    $arrWrapper[1][37] = "Y"
    $arrWrapper[1][38] = "B"
    $arrWrapper[1][39] = "SS"
    $arrWrapper[1][40] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][41] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][42] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][43] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][44] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][45] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][46] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][47] = "a"
    $arrWrapper[1][48] = "c"
    $arrWrapper[1][49] = "e"
    $arrWrapper[1][50] = "e"
    $arrWrapper[1][51] = "e"
    $arrWrapper[1][52] = "e"
    $arrWrapper[1][53] = "i"
    $arrWrapper[1][54] = "i"
    $arrWrapper[1][55] = "i"
    $arrWrapper[1][56] = "i"
    $arrWrapper[1][57] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][58] = "n"
    $arrWrapper[1][59] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][60] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][61] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][62] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][63] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][64] = "o"
    $arrWrapper[1][65] = "u"
    $arrWrapper[1][66] = "u"
    $arrWrapper[1][67] = "u"
    $arrWrapper[1][68] = "u"
    $arrWrapper[1][69] = "y"
    $arrWrapper[1][70] = "y"
    $arrWrapper[1][71] = "b"
    $arrWrapper[1][72] = "y"
    $arrWrapper[1][73] = "R"
    $arrWrapper[1][74] = "r"

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 75; $i++)
    {
        $pet = $strRemove.replace($arrWrapper[0][$i],$arrWrapper[1][$i])
    }

    return $pet
}
```

I just wrote a function which replaces a string with special characters with a a string with normal characters. Problem: It does not change the special characters. If I `Write-Host` the variable after I "replaced" it stays the same.

Comment: You perform each replacement operation on `$strRemove` and assign the result to `$pet`, hence only the last replacement (`r`->`r`) persists and is returned. Put `$pet = $strRemove` before the last loop in your function.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Do you mean if ($i = 74){$pet = $strRemove}

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote. And just to state the obvious, of course you also need to change `$strRemove.Replace()` into `$pet.Replace()`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Still does not work..  `$pet = $strRemove
 for ($i = 0; $i -lt 75; $i++)
 { 
  $pet = $pet.replace($arrWrapper[0][$i],$arrWrapper[1][$i])
 }
 return $pet`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Replace special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829919/powershell-replace-special-characters)

Comment: The way you're filling your array is broken. If you insist on doing it that way you should make the array an [actual 2-dimenstional array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9397385/1630171). However, I strongly recommend using the answer to the question LotPings referenced instead. It's a far superior approach to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I should change your code to somthing like:

change the last part to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 75; $i++)
{
    $strRemove = $strRemove.replace($arrWrapper[0][$i], $arrWrapper[1])[$i]
}
return $strRemove
```

Or a little suggestion for better readability:
(and more powershell minded)

```
$strRemove = "This is a small tést to convert $'s in to €'s!"
$Wrapper = $null
$Wrapper = @{
    'é' = 'e'
    '€' = 'Euro'
    '$' = 'Dollar'
}
$Wrapper.Keys | foreach-object{
    $strRemove = $strRemove.replace("$_" , $Wrapper[$_])
}
$strRemove
```